# Azure AD only supports 2 entries per custom extension?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a custom schemaExtension to my User entity in Azure AD.

The entity has 3 fields Id, Name and Date. I want to store multiple entries for this extension for each user.

```
{
  "ext<8char>_entity": {
  "Id":"3d005aa0-fe72-4ac8-b7da-50d6b524cab3",
  "Name":"my name",
  "Date":"1.1.2017"
 }
}
```

Then I created 2 entries with:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>/extensions
```

Upon third try I get back this message: **Maximum number of extensions values supported per application is 2.** Oh dear...

Can I change the limit value? Can I even store this kind of values in Azure AD? Does it make sense to store this kind of user related data in Azure AD?

EDIT:
We would like to tie a schema extension above to an organization, which has a list of different terms of services with values Id, Name, Date. There number of rows is 1, but we could add new terms of service when we need it. On the other hand we want to extend the User entity with "join table", where we gather all information about when a user agreed to different terms of service specified in the first extension. We think, it's best to store this in AD, since it's our master user repository (external) and we would like to keep this in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to understand your scenarios a little more clearly here - what custom app data do you want to store, why and why do you need multiple extension instances on an object?

We can change this limit, but it's in place because we don't want the feature to be abused (given other limits) and we couldn't think of good scenarios where the same extension would be written multiple times to the same object.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This seems reasonable (although please check that the 256 byte string limit is OK for your terms of service).  Do you offer multiple terms of service, or would you just update the single term of service?  Are you planning to do this as a URL to your terms of service pages (this would probably give you the most flexibility).  We don't support multi-valued extension properties, but this is also something we are investigating.

Comment: I will not use the exact content of the service there, just the reference (ID) and probably some URL. And for each TOS (if its a new one or updated one), we want a seperate record. So you are saying currently we can not store more than 2, right? Do you suggest other solution within Azure AD or Azure cloud that we could use for that?

Comment: How many more than 2 do you need?  We may be able to expand this.

Comment: I think 10 should be OK, for some time. But it should be maybe even more for future proof.